# Strange NoClassDefFoundError in jar

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I've compiled my Android app with external jar library (Intersult http) and guess what.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.intersult.net.https.HttpsClient
        at com.intersult.net.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at com.intersult.net.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:699)
        at com.intersult.net.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:171)
        at com.intersult.net.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
        at com.intersult.net.http.NtlmHttpURLConnection.connect(NtlmHttpURLConnection.java:55)
        at com.intersult.net.http.NtlmHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(NtlmHttpURLConnection.java:214)
        at com.peachinc.italiawire.network.NtlmTransport.call(NtlmTransport.java:106)
        at com.peachinc.italiawire.network.NtlmTransport.call(NtlmTransport.java:53)
        at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.call(Transport.java:255)
        at com.peachinc.italiawire.network.HttpRequests.getTransCalendar(HttpRequests.java:145)
        at com.peachinc.italiawire.FrmMain$1.run(FrmMain.java:120)
```

As you can see, both classes, HttpsClient and AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection lie in the same package and in the same jar lib. But one of them is loaded correctly and second one is not. So what's going on here?

Tried to clean, rebuild and clean via gradle commandline. It didn't work.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError can indicate a dependency failure - like a failing static initializer, etc. Can you have a look at/post the full stack trace?

Comment: Can you verify in the import you have the right import. Sometimes the class names are same in several libraries, just the package name differs. Make sure you have imported the right class. Can you check. Because I know there is also an Apache HttpClient instance with different package name.

Comment: You could make a fat/shaded jar which has all the depencies.

Comment: To be more clear, you can have in the import `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`, but you are using `com.intersult.net.https.HttpsClient` in the method. As you see, the names are the same, but the package names are different. And the method where you pass that reference is expecting a different HttpClient.

Comment: I've checked very carefully, the class com.intersult.net.https.HttpsClient is present in its correct package in the lib. Imports are correct too.

Comment: Do you have ProGuard enabled?

Comment: Did you add your library jar to the the application. because I was reading now this error is thrown, when there is no class definition found inside you compiled class. I am looking at this [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html). Good read.

Comment: " 1. A simple example of NoClassDefFoundError is class belongs to a missing JAR file or JAR was not added into classpath or sometimes jar's name has been changed by someone like in my case one of my colleague has changed tibco.jar into tibco_v3.jar and the program is failing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and I were wondering what's wrong."

Comment: Do you use gradle or maven? Make sure the XML contains the jar reference, so that it is added to the Android .apk file.

Comment: Proguard is disabled

Comment: Jernej K, read the log again. It loads AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection class, which is in the same lib. But it doesn't loads the HttpsClient.

Comment: All the names are correct. I've decompiled the jar and checked again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106024/discussion-between-user1748526-and-jernej-k).